# Solve transcendent modified Bessel function equation

Tags: roots, bessel-functions

I would like to solve an equation of this type:

$$A-BK_0(\kappa r)-CK_1(\kappa r)=0\ \ \  \text{with}\ A,B,C,\kappa\in\mathbb{R},\ \text{known}$$

i.e. I am looking for the zeros of the l.h.s. I am not aware whether this kind of problem can be solved analytically in an explicit way. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure if  you can somehow use $ \frac{d K_0(x)}{d x} = -K_1(x)$ so that you are looking for the zeros of $ \frac{d K_0(x)}{d x} -B' K_0(x) + A' = 0$.